# Laravel Eloquent relations issue

Tags: php, laravel

Hello i am new to laravel. I am trying to build relationship between two tables.

Method in my controler

```
public function show()
    {
        $users = users::all();
        dd($users->art);
        die;
        return View('test')->with('ime');
    }
```

user model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Articles;

class users extends Model
{
    protected $fillable =['name','email','password'];
    public function  setNameAttribute($data)
    {
         $this->attributes['name'] = strtolower($data).'Duca';
    }

    public function scopeNametor($query)
    {
        $query->where('name','ero');
    }

    public function art()
    {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Articles');  
    }
}
```

article Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Articles extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\users');  
    }
}
```

I set foreign key

```
user.id to articles.user_id
```

also i add index to articles.user_id field.

But i get error

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$art
```

Somehow laravel do not recognize art as method, but treat it as property. Something i am doing wrong. I try sometjing like this but no luck

```
dd($users->art()-get()->toArray());
```

Where could be problem. i think this could be easy to resolve

Comment: come let resovle this together

Comment: it seems i only have date from one table users

Comment: somehow i get Unknown column 'articles.users_id' in 'where ... i dont have users_id field anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i found error you cant use  $users = users::all(); it gonna return whole colection try something like this  `$users = users::first();`

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour as stated in the Laravel Docs:

> Once the relationship is defined, we may retrieve the related record using Eloquent's dynamic properties. Dynamic properties allow you to access relationship functions as if they were properties defined on the model

[Laravel - Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships)

The example given:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the phone record associated with the user.
     */
    public function phone()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Phone');
    }
}
```

To access the phone relationship:

```
$phone = User::find(1)->phone;
```

Comment: somehow i get Unknown column 'articles.users_id' in 'where ... i dont have users_id field anywhere

Comment: @AleksandraStus Have you created a `user_id` field for your Articles table?
This should be in your Articles migration:
`$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();`

Comment: It may be down to how you have named your models.Following convention, your model `users` should be named `User`, and `Articles` should be `Article`. This actually matters as Larvel will take these model names and work out the name of the corresponding tables. For example a model named `Animal` will have an assumed table of `animals`. Try adding `protected $table = 'user';` in the User model, and `protected $table = 'articles';` within the Aritcle model. This will explicitly specify the names of the tables.